# C: Segmentation Fault (core dumped) for processing file

Tags: c, linux

In C, when executing my program, I get a segmentation fault (core dumped error) and have no clue why. The program takes a .class file and converts it to binary. I suspect the issue is with the temporary file. This is on a Linux/Raspberry system.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
static unsigned int numFiles = 0;
static unsigned long numBytes = 0;

FILE* rawf;
char* raw_file_name_end = ".raw_ujc";
char * rawfilename;

static void byte(unsigned char v){
    if(numBytes) printf(", ");

    printf((numBytes & 0x0F) ? "0x%02X" : "\n\t0x%02X", v);

    fwrite(&v,sizeof(v),1,rawf);

    numBytes++;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    const char* self = argv[0];
    int c;
    const char* classCvt = 0;
    long len;

    if(argc == 1){

        fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: %s [-c <path_to_classCvt>] <file 1> [<file 2> [ <file 3> [...]]] > result.c\n", self);
        return -1;
    }

    argv++;
    argc--;

    if(argv[0][0] == '-' && argv[0][1] == 'c' && !argv[0][2]){

        classCvt = argv[1];
        argv += 2;
        argc -= 2;
    }

    printf("\nService optimized bytecode = {\n\t");

    while(argc--){
        char* filename = *argv;

        rawfilename = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(filename)-strlen(".class")) + sizeof(char) * strlen(raw_file_name_end)+1);

        strncpy(rawfilename,filename,(strlen(filename)-strlen(".class")));
        strcat(rawfilename,raw_file_name_end);
        fprintf(stderr, "rawfilename after alloc: %s \n", rawfilename);

        if(classCvt){

            char* t;

            static char template[] = "/tmp/myfileXXXXXX";
            char fname[PATH_MAX];

            strcpy(fname, template); /* Copy template */

            filename = mkstemp(fname);
            if(!filename){
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to create a tempfile: %d\n", self, errno);
                return -10;
            }

            t = malloc(strlen(filename) + strlen(classCvt) + strlen(*argv) + 32);
            if(!t){
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to alloc a small string. This is unlikely\n", self);
                free(t);
                return -11;
            }
            sprintf(t, "%s < %s > %s", classCvt, *argv, filename);

            if(system(t)){

                fprintf(stderr, "%s: system() fail: %d\n", self, errno);
                free(t);
                return -12;
            }
            free(t);
            unlink(fname);

        }

        FILE* f = fopen(filename, "r");
        rawf = fopen(rawfilename, "wb");

        if(!f){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open '%s': %d\n", self, *argv, errno);
            fclose(f);
            return -2;
        }
        if(!f){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open '%s': %d\n", self, *argv, errno);
            fclose(f);
            return -2;
        }
        if(fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END)){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to seek(1) in '%s': %d\n", self, *argv, errno);
            fclose(f);
            return -3;
        }
        len = ftell(f);
        if(len < 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to tell in '%s': %d\n", self, *argv, errno);
            fclose(f);
            return -4;
        }
        if(fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET)){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to seek(2) in '%s': %d\n", self, *argv, errno);
            fclose(f);
            return -5;
        }
        if(len > 0x00FFFFFFUL){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:  file '%s' is %lu bytes, while maximum allowable size is %lu.\n", self, *argv, len, 0x00FFFFFFUL);
            fclose(f);
            return -6;
        }

        byte(len >> 16);
        byte(len >> 8);
        byte(len);

        while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF){
            byte(c);
        }

        numFiles++;
        fclose(f);
        fclose(rawf);

        if(filename != *argv){
            unlink(filename);
            free(filename);
        }
        argv++;


    }

    byte(0);
    byte(0);
    byte(0);

    printf("\n};\n");

    fprintf(stderr, "%s: processed %u files, producing %lu (0x%lX) bytes of output\n", self, numFiles, numBytes, numBytes);
    fprintf(stderr, "rawfilename at end: %s \n", rawfilename);
    free(rawfilename);

    return 0;

}
```

The segfault happens after the print of:
"
rawfilename after alloc: ./../files//Test_Network.raw_ujc
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
"

Comment: posting the exact text of segfault would be nice

Comment: Also, with all the print statements, do you have an idea where the segfault happens?

Comment: Compile your code with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). **Use the debugger** (`gdb`), perhaps even on the `core` dump

Comment: what do you think you are doing here `filename = mkstemp(fname);` filename is a char pointer and `mkstemp` returns a file descriptor

Comment: I added some extra data.

@Seek Addo: I think I see what you mean. I've converted the code from the usage of tempnam but did so poorly. How would I best fix this?

Comment: @Sven `mkstemp` returns an int, so you have to assign it to integer not a char pointer.`mkstemp` returns -1 for error so your logic `!flename` makes no sense. You have to check if is -1 and then report error. And your fprintf with errno is wrong should be `fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to create a tempfile: %s\n", self, strerror(errno));` You want the error message not print the errno

Comment: GDB backtrace can help, please paste the crash output.

Comment: One thing contains gabage because of assigning the file descriptor to it `filename`, so this `FILE* f = fopen(filename, "r");` will operate on garbage

Comment: Also the strncpy followed immediately by strcat could be problematic - strncpy doesn't always append a null character.

Comment: `char* filename = *argv;` where `*argv` is equivalent to `*(argv + 0)` or `argv[0]` is dubious unless you actually want the program name as the filename. It also appears you are compiling without **warnings enabled** or are choosing to intentionally ignore `warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default] filename = mkstemp(fname);`

Comment: The code came from somebody else -- my purpose was to generate a unique filename to do stuff with but I believe I ran into threading issues with the use of tempname, so I tried out mkstemp.

More needs to be modified however, but I need the filename regardless... Thanks for the help, I'll start a new post to better figure out my initila problem